# adding jquery validation after form created

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, jquery-validate

I'm using a [jquery validation plugin](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation)

First I add the validation to the form:

```
$('#EmployeeForm').validate({
        rules: {
            "Employee.FirstName": "required",
            "Employee.PatronymicName": "required",
            "Employee.LastName": "required",
            "Employee.BirthDay": { required: true, date: true }
        },

        messages: {
            "Employee.FirstName": { required: "*" },
            "Employee.PatronymicName": { required: "*" },
            "Employee.LastName": { required: "*" },
            "Employee.BirthDay": { required: "*", date: "00.00.00 format" }
        }
    });
```

It works fine until here.  I then later a need to add validation rules to other form elements:

```
$('#Address_A.Phone1, #Address_A.Phone2, #Address_B.Phone1, #Address_B.Phone2')
            .rules("add", {
                digits: true
            });
```

Here I get an error:  **'form' is null or not an object**

I check, the form and all the elements in it are created before I add validation to it.
I cant figure out what's wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just a guess is `Address_A.Phone1` the id of your element?

If yes I guess your problems comes from the fact that you use `.` in your element id's. But jQuery won't understand e.g. `#Address_A.Phone1` as give me element with id `Address_A.Phone1` but instead will interpret this selector as: Give me element with id `Address_A` which has the class `Phone1`.

But actually this doesn't explain the error. Can you append on which line this error occurs. Is it in your code or inside the plugin code? If inside the plugin on which line

Answer (score 1):

I didn't ever use that plugin but from what I see in [documentation](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/rules#.22add.22rules) you should use normal jQuery selectors instead of `#Address_A.Phone1, #Address_A.Phone2, #Address_B.Phone1, #Address_B.Phone2` (well those also are normal selectors but they have no sense in normal usage).

So try to use something like this: `#EmployeeForm #first-name, #EmployeeForm #last-name`

Comment: You may be onto something here -- if he's using ASP.NET MVC, those may very well be the names of the fields, but he's using the id selector.  Perhaps it needs to be `[name=Address_A.Phone1]...`.  However, if the selectors where failing, it would simply not have anything to apply rules to and I don't think there would be an error.

Answer (score 1):

Is it possible that the latter is added a result that is returned by AJAX -- a result that might have replaced the form on the page?  Or perhaps in a separate "on load" section that might be running before the validation plugin has been applied?  I'd suggest using the unminified validation script and stepping through with the debugger (Firefox/Firebug would be my preference).  Put breakpoints in both the validation set up and the addition of the rules to see which is being hit first.  If the form is replaced via AJAX, you'll have to reapply the validation plugin to it before you add rules as the old form is no longer available.